# Error while connecting to BLE device using Gatttool

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using gatttool on Raspberry PI to connect to a BLE peripheral.
The connection fails with the error message "connect error: Too many levels of symbolic links (40)"

The following is the command & response log obtained with gatttool.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo gatttool -b 20:70:6a:10:01:81  -I
[20:70:6a:10:01:81][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to 20:70:6a:10:01:81
Error: connect error: Too many levels of symbolic links (40)

What is the issue here?
Thanks

Comment: same for me. It was running fine yesterday, did a system update (raspian), a firmware update (raspi-update) and boom

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue, and bringing the hci0 interface down and up helped me.

`sudo hciconfig hci0 down/up`

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 down
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
```

solved the issue for me, as described by user3493478, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user3493478, @contractorwolf,
It solved my problem to connect MiFlora to P4 (Raspbian)

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi#  gatttool -I -b C4:7C:8D:6C:9A:5A
[C4:7C:8D:6C:9A:5A][LE] connect
Attempting to connect to C4:7C:8D:6C:9A:5A
Error: connect error: Too many levels of symbolic links (40)

root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# hciconfig hci0 up
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# hciconfig hci0 down

[C4:7C:8D:6C:9A:5A][LE] connect
Attempting to connect to C4:7C:8D:6C:9A:5A
Connection successful
```